# Starting new activity from ListFragment using onListItemClick()

Tags: android, onclick

Right now I have an app that searches and returns items in a ListFragment.  I want to be able to make each ListFragment clickable, such that when it is clicked, a new activity starts using something like this:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, PlaceView.class);
    startActivity(i);
    //eventually data from the List will be passed to the new Activity...
}
```

The class that starts the ListFragment that I need to be clickable is as follows:

```
public class ResultsView extends FragmentActivity {

private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results_view);

        //Receive searchTerm from MainActivity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String searchTerm = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.SEARCH_TERM);

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_label_list);

        FragmentManager     fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        ListFragment list = new ListFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, list);

        // Let's set our list adapter to a simple ArrayAdapter.
        list.setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        FactualResponderFragment responder = (FactualResponderFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("RESTResponder");
        if (responder == null) {
            responder = new FactualResponderFragment();

            ft.add(responder, "RESTResponder");
        }

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("search_term", searchTerm);
        responder.setArguments(bundle);

        ft.commit();
    }

    public ArrayAdapter<String> getArrayAdapter() {
        return mAdapter;
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, PlaceView.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

So my questions are:

1) How do I set up the `onListItemClick()` to work with the `ListFragment list` that I am working with?

2) `ListView` doesn't have any XML attributes that relate to `onClick` or the like.  Does that not matter?

3) Where should the `onListItemClick()`, `onItemClickListener()` and anything else applicable be?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

Following Pramod's advice, I made a class: `ListFragmentClickable extends ListFragment`, and populated it with the following:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, PlaceView.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Eclipse tells me that `new Intent(this, PlaceView.class)` is not allowed, and that I only can say `Intent i = new Intent();`. The error is "The constructor Intent(ListFragmentClickable, Class) is undefined." I tried instantiating the Intent as Eclipse suggested, and then added `i.setClass(this, PlaceView.class)` and `i.setClassName(this, PlaceView.class)` but it didn't work as I got the same error.

1) How do I get around this error and override the method as planned?

2) If I can't do that, and have to use `Intent i = new Intent();`, how do I tell the intent what class we're even aiming at?

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: "The constructor Intent(ListFragmentClickable, Class<PlaceView>) is undefined."

Comment: Is PlaceView an activity? Based on the name is not.

Comment: PlaceView is an activity, i know my naming is bad. sorry!

Comment: check out my comment on your context

Comment: very clear question +1...have fun with your new found SO powers!  Make sure you accept an answer from all previous questions.

Comment: thanks for the reminder, forgot that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend a class from listfragment then override the listitemclick function.

Comment: Thanks Pramod, can you please elaborate on that a little bit?  I'm a pretty big noob when it comes to all this...

Comment: Visit this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html and this http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/a-listfragment-application-in-android/

Comment: alright i understand what you're saying actually.  if i do that and then create my 'list' from the extended class rather than ListFragment, will the activity start upon click?

Comment: Yes. Try it and let me know

Comment: Added more info into main body of my question (see "EDIT:") as what you suggested isn't working without errors...  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Just try this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), YourClassName.class);
startActivity(Intent intent);
```

Where "YourClassName" is the type of the class you wish to call into.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent((context),class)
```

where class is a recognized type that works with intent. Specifically this is Activity, Service, etc. Also context should be coming from your application **not** from the encapsulated listview, which you are achieving through using `this`. Use getApplicationContext() or grab it from your application class, you need valid context.

If PlaceView is not a recognized type then you cannot do what you're trying to do.

Comment: So then should context be coming from ResultsView, which is the activity where the ListFragment is being used?  I assume I call for the context in the modified ListFragment class, so I have set it up as follows.  Before the modified onListItemClick method, I have `Context ctx = getApplicationContext();` but it tells me that the method is undefined for ListFragmentClickable... Do I need to call for context within ResultsView and then pass it to the ListFragmentClickable class?

Comment: You probably should pass in the Context to the customized class.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily get context by using using this "getActivity().getApplicationContext()"