# How to start activity from a ListFragment via onListItemClick

Tags: android

Hi im developing a BLE App. After i scanned for devices and Display them into a ListFragment i want to get Services and Characteristics of them. If i implemented that in onListItemClick everything is fine i get the Services and the Characteristics. But now i want a new Activity started while i click on one Item.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    rightPosition = position + 1;
    connectToDevice();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ServiceCharacteristicAvtivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

If i do like above my App crashes really looked for a solution but didnt get my failure. Maybe it is so easy that i dont see it. Can someone help me out?

The Log i get is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fkoffle.blescanner/com.example.fkoffle.blescanner.ServiceCharacteristicAvtivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:356)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:325)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:286)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
```

The activity i want to start is just

```
public class ServiceCharacteristicAvtivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_service_characteristic_avtivity);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please add the logs?

Comment: one "solution" i found didnt helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514831/starting-new-activity-from-listfragment-using-onlistitemclick

Comment: Sorry Eselfar of course i can add the logs

Comment: add more code and logs

Comment: Can you post code of the activity you are trying to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your manifest file, add the following theme.

```
  <activity
        android:name=". ServiceCharacteristicAvtivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

As your logcat suggests, you need to use `Theme.AppCompat` or any descendent (like I used in above example).

Comment: Oh my God... that was the failure i didnt watched in my manifest thx to all

Answer (score 1):

If you are extending an `AppCompatActivity` you need to use an AppCompat or any descendant theme.

You can use one of the below themes in the manifest of your activity.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

eg.

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the activity you are calling is extending Activity, while your layout is having elements that comes under AppCompatActivity.
So in your activity, do something like this:

```
public class ServiceCharacteristicAvtivity extends AppCompatActivity {
....
....
}
```

If it isn't the case, can you share your layout code and acytivity code?